# Sum of independent errors

Tags: homework-and-exercises, statistics, error-analysis

During a physics lab we stumbled upon a little problem. The measuring device was unstable, oscillating between two values. We were told to write down the average with the half-difference between the values as error. There is also the error on the measure due to the instrument's resolution.

Now I have to consider the global error over the measure and I'm going to sum both errors. Is it correct?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to combine measurement error with statistic error](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/23441/)

Comment: @KyleKanos the difference is that in my question my errors are both systematic :)

Comment: The accepted answer to the question I pointed states *the ultimate standard deviation of the measured value $\sigma$ should be the result of all individual sources (we will index by $i$), under the assumption that all sources of variation are also 
normally distributed.*

Comment: @KyleKanos but I don't think that my sources of variation are normally distributed.. If you are sure that I'm wrong, could you explain me why, please?

Comment: The answer by Lubos in the aforementioned question discusses your latest comment.